# Очередь через двусвязный список (не используя шаблоны STL) C++

Tags: c++, очередь, двусвязный-список

Вот мой двусвязный список:

```
struct Num
{
    int number;
    bool ring;
    Num *next, *prev;
};

class List
{
protected :
    Num *head, *tail;

public :
     List():head(NULL),tail(NULL){};
    ~List();
    int genNum();
    void Add(int x);
    bool Remove(int i);
};
```

Добавление элемента :

```
void List::Add(int x)
{
Num *temp = new Num;
temp->next = NULL;
temp->number = x;

if(head != NULL)
{
    temp->prev = tail;
    tail->next = temp;
    tail= temp;
}

else
{
    temp->prev = NULL;
    head = tail = temp;
}
}
```

И удаление :

```
bool List::Remove(int idx)
{
Num *current = head;
Num *temp = NULL;
int i = 0;

while(current->next != NULL)
{
    if(i != idx)
    {
        current = current->next;
        i++;
    }

    else
    {
        if (idx == 0)
        {
            temp = head;
            head = current;
        }

        else
        {
            temp = current->prev;
            current->prev = temp->prev;
            current->prev->next = current;
        }

        delete temp;
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
}
```

Как из него сделать очередь? (можно сделать наследование очереди от списка)

Comment: реализуйте только функциональности, присущие очереди.

Answer (score 2):

```
class List
{
protected :
    Num *head, *tail;

public :
    List():head(NULL),tail(NULL){}
    ~List();  
    List(const List& t);
    List& operator =(const List& other);
    void push(const int&);
    void pop();
    size_t size() const;
    bool operator <(const list& other) const; // если нужно   
    bool empty() const  { return !head; }
    Num& back() const { return *tail; }
    Num& front() const { return *head; }         
};
```

попытайтесь реализовать  примерно такой класс